# Multiple checkbox in list

Tags: jquery, html

I have made a list in which there is a checkbox in each list items. I want that if any one of the child checkbox in the list item is checked, then parent checkbox is also checked.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="parent">
<ul>
       <li><input type="checkbox" class="child"></li>

       <li><input type="checkbox" class="child"></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: I also want to know what had you try so far?

Comment: Do you have multiple parent checkboxes ?

Comment: yes i have multiple checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works 2 ways. Children will be checked when parent box is checked, in case you need and I think it makes sense. https://jsfiddle.net/5bea6Lty/

```
var count = 0;
$('#parent').change(function() {
    $('.child').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked')).change();
});
$('.child').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    count++;
  else
    count--;
  $('#parent').prop('checked', (count <= 0) ? 0 : 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this might be helpful to you...

```
$(function () {
    $("li:has(li) > input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        $(this).siblings('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    $("input[type='checkbox'] ~ ul input[type = 'checkbox']").change(function () {
        $(this).closest("li: has(li)").children("input[type = 'checkbox']").prop('checked', $(this).closest('ul').find("input[type = 'checkbox']").is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

Comment: pls add some explanation for OP

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.child').change(function() {
    var allChild=$('.child');
    var check=false;
    $.each(allChild).function(i,child){
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
           check=true;
      }
    }
    $('#parent').attr("checked", check);           
});
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Define a JavaScript function to link child elements with their parents:

```
function checkParent(parentId, childId) {
  document.getElementById(parentId).checked = document.getElementById(childId).checked;
}
```

Then call the function, when a child element is clicked:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="parent">
<ul>
  <li><input id="childOne" type="checkbox" class="child" onclick="checkParent('parent', 'childOne')"></li>

  <li><input id="childTwo" type="checkbox" class="child" onclick="checkParent('parent', 'childTwo')"></li>
 </ul>
```

Notice that I added ids to the child elements as well.